# why is mysql giving me a mix of my database values

Tags: mysql

so I made a database which contains 2 tables, table1 and table2.
if I use SELECT*FROM table 1 I get somthing like:

**name1,adres1,city1**

**name2,adress2,city2**

and if i use SELECT*FROM table 2 I get somthing like:

**name1,gender1,hobies1**

**name2,gender2,hobbies2**

but when i use SELECT*FROM table1,table2 I get:

**name1,adres1,city1,name1,gender1,hobies1**

**name1,adress1,city1,name2,gender2,hobbies2**

**name2,adres2,city2,name2,gender2,hobies2**

**name2,adress1,city2,name1,gender1,hobbies1**

why is this happening?

Comment: "why is this happening?" --- because that's what you exactly queried: a permutation of all rows from both tables

Comment: When you select like that from 2 tables without where conditions you get union of both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're experiencing is simply the result of Cartesian Product.
You are selecting every possible combination of the rows in those two tables.